# Changing colour of navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change the background colour of the navigation bar but am having trouble:

```
let colourRGBs: [[CGFloat]] = [[247, 247, 247], [38, 123, 238], [93, 204, 3]]
let colourTitles: [String] = ["Default", "Blue", "Green"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return colourTitles.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PickNavBarColourCell", for: indexPath) as! PickNavBarColourCell
    let RGB = colourRGBs[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: RGB[0]/255.0, green: RGB[1]/255.0, blue: RGB[2]/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    cell.configureCell(text: colourTitles[indexPath.row])
    if indexPath.row == passOnNavBarColour.colour {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(indexPath.row, forKey: "NavBarColour")
    passOnNavBarColour.colour = indexPath.row
    tableView.reloadData()
    let RGB = colourRGBs[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: RGB[0]/255.0, green: RGB[1]/255.0, blue: RGB[2]/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}
```

When I do this for blue for example, this is the result:
[image]

It is a lot fainter than it should be.

I have tried the following code with:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

which I run before setting the cells background colour

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: RGB[0]/255.0, green: RGB[1]/255.0, blue: RGB[2]/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

however this results in no colour change whatsoever.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Did you put your following code to viewDidLoad method ?

Comment: No - that code is of the whole view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `navigationBar.barTintColor`

From Apple's Document:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/#1654191

> You can specify a custom tint color for a navigation bar background using the barTintColor property. Setting this property overrides the default color inferred from the bar style. As with all UIView subclasses, you can control the color of the interactive elements within navigation bars, including button images and titles, using the tintColor property.

Could not change `navigationBar.backgroundColor`, because it is hidden by a few views.
You can see the view hierarchy by a break point.

[image]

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

Navigation Bar:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green
```

Replace greenColor with whatever UIColor you want, you can use an RGB too if you prefer.

Navigation Bar Text:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orange]
```

Replace orangeColor with whatever color you like.

Tab Bar:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.brown
```

Tab Bar Text:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.yellow
```

On the last two, replace brownColor and yellowColor with the color of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this simple line in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blue
```